# Adacore GPS error message "Could not locate executable on path: svn"

Tags: svn, gps, ada

I have been using GPS for a while and keep getting this error every time I open GPS and every time I click in certain places like the locations of a search in a project:

`[2018-12-05 10:02:05] Could not locate executable on path: svn`

`SVN error:`

When I build or compile a project everything works fine but it is annoying to see this message popping up every few minutes or seconds.

I would really appreciate a solution to this or simply a way to dissable the error message. I have checked GPS options but I can't find anything to solve my problem.

Thanks a lot.

Edit: I am using GPS 2017 (20170515) on Windows.

Comment: The best way to install development tools like [tag:svn] will depend on which operating system you're using.

Comment: Which version of GPS?

Comment: Hi, I will add the information to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing the same error running GNAT on my MacBook OSX. I recalled I may have carelessly made some changes in OSX. I reinstalled GNAT and then carefully updated my Environmental $PATH to include the location of the GNAT install, which in my case was /Users/MyName/opt/bin, and that cleared up the error. Maybe something similar for your Windows set up.